# GMS Task<TResult> class: can getResult() return null if isSuccessful()?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services

There is recently a @Nullable change to GMS tasks library. The first few lines of decompiled .class looks like

```
public abstract class Task<TResult> {
    public Task() {
    }

    public abstract boolean isComplete();

    public abstract boolean isSuccessful();

    public abstract boolean isCanceled();

    @Nullable
    public abstract TResult getResult();
```

Previously my Kotlin code compiled:

```
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            task.result.user?.getIdToken(false)?.addOnCompleteListener { taskk ->
                this.emailIdTokenCompleteListener()(taskk)
            }
```

After updating some gms `play-services-zzz` dependencies the code now has compile error:

> LoginActivity.kt: (148, 28): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type AuthResult?

The question is, does `isSuccessful() == true` imply that `getResult != null`? Or would it just be better to change the if test to `if (task.result != null)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the Kotlin compiler failing to smart-cast the result to a NonNull type based on the result of isSuccessful, this can happen when interacting with both Java and Kotlin code.

In Kotlin 1.3 an implementation of "Contracts" was added to the language to allow developers to add meta data about a method in a format that the IDE can use to statically analyze and infer type (smart-cast).

See Section 1.2 "Returns and Implies" https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-contracts-make-great-deals-with-the-compiler-f524e57f11c

So with contracts it would correctly smart-cast if the implementation looked like this:

```
open class Task<T> {
    var result: T? = null
        private set

    fun isSuccessful(): Boolean {
        contract {
            returns(true) implies (result != null)
        }
        return result != null
    }
}
```

In your case however you probably want to throw on another safe call operator `?` and call your `!task.isSuccessful` code with the Elvis operator `?:` like this:

```
if (task.isSuccessful) {
        task.result?.user?.getIdToken(false)?.addOnCompleteListener { taskk ->
            this.emailIdTokenCompleteListener()(taskk)
        } ?: handleFailure() // Defensively call just in case
} else {
    handleFailure()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are GMS tasks that can return *null* at runtime. For example [FirebaseAnalytics.getAppInstanceId()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#getAppInstanceId())

So you should check the result for null and not rely on the annotations.